# Objects slowing down

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction

I know that when an object is moving on a suface it slows down due to friction , now since the kinetic friction on the object is constant (and it's the net force on the object since the normal force and gravity cancel each other out ) then the object will be decelarating at constant acceleration . Am I right ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, everything you say is correct assuming, as we do in general, that dynamic friction (kinetic friction) is pretty much constant. If you are interested in more accuracy than that general assumption provides, then we can talk about how in reality dynamic fiction does slightly vary with speed, typically decreasing with speed depending on the materials involved, etc.